# Difference between JMX Garbage Collection and a System.gc()?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jmx

When studying the behavior of my application in VisualVM, I encountered this and was puzzled, I figured that the JMX call to Perform a Garbage Collection would have the same functionality as calling `System.gc()`, however in all environments that I have tried it on, the JMX call always results in a smaller heap usage then the call to `System.gc()`, what functionally is the difference?

[image]

You can see on the final drop - I manually clicked the Perform GC button, my usage dropped a bit lower then it had been with the regular system collections. Thoughts on why this might be?

I have tried this in multiple environments, leaving the collections up to the system and manually invoking  `System.gc()`, and every time the JMX call will clear a lot more.

As you can see in the posted image, the system garbage collection IS running, the JMX call just clears *more*, the question is what is the difference between these two calls?

Comment: it depends on your application usage and object allocation. If there are lot of short lived objects generated in your app that are not collected , though frequent GC will not take place as GC itself is a overhead/stop the world. so if you perform GC manually these objects can be cleared.

Comment: JavaDoc for `System.gc()`: "Calling the gc method **suggests** that the Java Virtual Machine expend effort toward recycling unused objects in order to make the memory they currently occupy available for quick reuse. When control returns from the method call, the Java Virtual Machine has made **a best effort** to reclaim space from all discarded objects." In practice, it could even decide to just do nothing if Java thinks the result is not worth the work. The "forced" jmx call will probably enforce the GC to do all he can. Depends on the actual code.

Comment: @tb, I apologize if my question is unclear, I have edited it slightly to better explain myself. You can see in the posted image that the `System.gc()` call is being made regularly, the JMX call came towards the end where my heap usage drops to nearly 0; the question is what is the difference between the System garbage collection and the JMX garbage collection? THe seem to have different functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This must be circumstantial (due to it being called at a different point in program's execution or some similar factor) - the Sun's implementation of `MemoryMXBean`, `sun.management.MemoryImpl`:

```
public void gc() {
    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
}
```

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/management/MemoryImpl.java#MemoryImpl.gc%28%29

`System.gc()`:

```
public static void gc() {
    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
}
```

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/System.java#System.gc%28%29

So there's really no functional difference between the two ways to suggest garbage collection, and the only difference is in when, and from what thread, it is called.

Comment: Huh, interesting. I will have to try this out on some other Java applets. It seems odd to me that in multiple trials with this one application I consistently saw the aforementioned behavior. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

In general it's the same, the MemoryMXBean.gc() just call System.gc().

**MemoryMXBean.gc()**

> void gc() Runs the garbage collector. The call gc() is effectively
>   equivalent to the call:  System.gc()   See Also: System.gc()

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html

**System.gc()**

> public static void gc() Runs the garbage collector. Calling the gc
>   method suggests that the Java Virtual Machine expend effort toward
>   recycling unused objects in order to make the memory they currently
>   occupy available for quick reuse. When control returns from the method
>   call, the Java Virtual Machine has made a best effort to reclaim space
>   from all discarded objects.
>
> The call System.gc() is effectively equivalent to the call:
>
> Runtime.getRuntime().gc()   See Also: Runtime.gc()

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc()

**Runtime.gc()**

> public void gc() Runs the garbage collector. Calling this method
>   suggests that the Java virtual machine expend effort toward recycling
>   unused objects in order to make the memory they currently occupy
>   available for quick reuse. When control returns from the method call,
>   the virtual machine has made its best effort to recycle all discarded
>   objects. The name gc stands for "garbage collector". The virtual
>   machine performs this recycling process automatically as needed, in a
>   separate thread, even if the gc method is not invoked explicitly.
>
> The method System.gc() is the conventional and convenient means of
>   invoking this method.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#gc()